# What are the tags for terrible code?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Is there a tag or set of tags that indicate that ***I have a problem with this ... { } ... terrible code/issue and I'm coming to SO for help*** ?

I went through some of my older posts where I was addressing some of my "bad code" and just happened to notice that some tags had been removed from both the question and all-around use on the site (specifically, [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack)).

Terrible code comes in many different forms, and I still see some specific examples of tags (like [spaghetti-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spaghetti-code)) used to describe a troubled code base.

I'm looking for a tag that states "I'm looking for a temporary solution to a bad problem" (I still feel [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack) is a reasonable tag - even tools like Visual Studio come pre-configured to recognize comments that start with "HACK:" in source files).

***What tag (or tags) am I looking for?***

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for sounds like a meta tag. Those were [dealt a death blow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) a few years ago. One that specifically calls out terrible code would be particularly problematic, considering that everyone can add tags to other people's questions.

Comment: And it would be used for trolling.

Comment: Honest question. Did the spaghetti code tag slip through the cracks, or is there something special about it that I'm missing?

Comment: @Michael It looks like it slipped through the cracks as a synonym for `coding-style`, which is also not a great tag.